# How to encode an object with ABIEncoder V2?

Tags: solidity, truffle, abiencoderv2

How to encode an object with ABIEncoder V2?

For example, this one:

```
{
  items: [
    {  
      str: "str",
      num: 5,
      bol: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Solidity struct:

```
struct Item {
  string str;
  uint   num;
  bool   bol;
}

struct Arg {
  Item[] items;
}
```

Comment: Neither one of these (`str`, `num` and `bol`) is a valid type in Solidity. I sincerely doubt that this object can be encoded.

Comment: @goodvibration these are keys, not types

Comment: Yes, but those keys should be representing Solidity types (i.e., the types of your variables rather than the names of your variables).

Answer (score 2):

See the example below

### Warning from Remix: Experimental features are turned on. Do not use experimental features on live deployments.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
// Enable the ABI v2 Coder
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract AbiTwoTest {

    struct Item {
        string str;
        uint   num;
        bool   bol;
    }

    struct Arg {
        Item[] items;
    }

    mapping (address => Arg) itemsByUser;

    // User struct in the event
    event ItemAdded(string indexed str, uint num, bool bol);

    // User struct in the method signature
    function addItem(Item memory _item) public {
        itemsByUser[msg.sender].items.push(_item);
        emit ItemAdded(_item.str, _item.num, _item.bol);
    }

    // User struct in the returns
    function item(address addr) public view returns (Arg memory items) {
        return itemsByUser[addr];
    }
}
```

**Remix Testing**

*Add Item*
[image]

*Read Item*
[image]

**Contract ABI**

```
[
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "string",
                        "name": "str",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "num",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "bool",
                        "name": "bol",
                        "type": "bool"
                    }
                ],
                "internalType": "struct AbiTwoTest.Item",
                "name": "_item",
                "type": "tuple"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addItem",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "str",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "num",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "bol",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ItemAdded",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "addr",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "item",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "components": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "str",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "num",
                                "type": "uint256"
                            },
                            {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "bol",
                                "type": "bool"
                            }
                        ],
                        "internalType": "struct AbiTwoTest.Item[]",
                        "name": "items",
                        "type": "tuple[]"
                    }
                ],
                "internalType": "struct AbiTwoTest.Arg",
                "name": "items",
                "type": "tuple"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically encode arbitrary object into a tuple?

Comment: I based my answer off of this link. ethers.js seems to automatically encode the provided json object when it creates and sends the transaction. https://blog.ricmoo.com/solidity-abiv2-a-foray-into-the-experimental-a6afd3d47185 would this do what you are looking for?

Comment: Wow. Solidity v0.8.0 has JUST BEEN RELEASED WITH ABI coder v2 activated by default!!!